# How to parse xml with dataclass (from xsData)?

Tags: python, xml, xsd

My program requires that for the right type of xml file to use the right xsd. So it has to happen dynamically (xsd will be updated over time).
So I downloaded the xsd (over 40 patterns,with import so its kind of nested) to create the appropriate classes from them in python I used :

`xsdata "route to files" --package xsd.models`

To parse it with xml i tried many solutions and none of them works:

```
parser = XmlParser()

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
            content = file.read()
            if extracted_url in content:
                code_tree = ast.parse(content)
                extracted_class = None
                for node in ast.walk(code_tree):
                    if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef):
                        extracted_class = node.name
                        pprint(extracted_class)
                        break
                if extracted_class:
                    module_spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(node.name,os.path.join(directory, filename))
                    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(module_spec)
                    module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)

                    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
                        if inspect.isclass(obj) and name == extracted_class:
                            sf_class = obj
                            pprint(f"here we use parser, for class {sf_class}")
                            pprint(f"in file {os.path.join(directory, filename)}")

                            order = parser.parse(os.path.join(directory, filename), clazz=sf_class)
                            pprint(order)
                            break
```

this finds the appropriate class for the given xml but throws an error on parsing
returns: `xsdata.exceptions.ParserError: Failed to create target class "SomeClass"`

I also tried without searching for the appropriate path, only completed manually:

```
from xsd.models import SomeClass
xml_file = route_xml
root = etree.parse(xml_file).getroot()
parser = XmlParser(context=XmlContext())
order = parser.parse(root, SomeClass)
```

return: `xsdata.exceptions.ParserError: Unknown property...`

So my question is did I "unpackage" it wrong using xsdata or is the parsing error?

unfortunately I have no influence on the content of xml and xsd (they are provided externally and I cannot "modify" them)